# What are Harley Quinn's superpowers?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad-2016, harley-quinn

In the *Suicide Squad* movie, what exactly are Harley Quinn's superpowers? There is a scene in which she is immersed in a liquid by The Joker but it's not clear what transformation if any occurs there. Or is she "merely" a Peak Human?

Comment: She has no superpowers.

Comment: She's super-annoying

Comment: Omnipresence, and a high tolerance for lite-beer, at least if last year's Halloween parties were any indication.

Comment: The power of fan-service.

Comment: IN the comics, in one version of her origin (from the Batman: Harley Quinn Prestige format one-shot released in 1999, I think, which I also think was her first appearance in the mainstream DC Universe), Poison Ivy had given her some concoction that gave her enhanced strength (and possibly agility), and an immunity to most toxins. However, it's not entirely clear if that's been retained since then (especially into the New 52 version).

Answer (score 18):

Harley Quinn does not have any superpowers. She's just a human being, like the Joker himself (albeit with some problems). See [Wikia](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Harley_Quinn) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn) for more information.

Regarding the "scene in which she is immersed in a liquid":

> She [...] allowed herself to fall into the vat of chemicals that
>   created the Joker years back. [...] Harleen awakened with the same
>   frontotemporal dementia that her lover received via exposure to the
>   chemicals and oxygen deprivation as the Joker broke down into maniacal
>   laughter.

<sup>[Wikia](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Harley_Quinn#Chemical_wedding)</sup>

While this may or may not be true for the movie version, the *comic book* version of Harley Quinn has "superhuman agility, enhanced strength, intelligence" listed under her powers. ([dccomics.com](http://www.dccomics.com/characters/harley-quinn))

Comment: Would've been nice if that Wikia author cited their sources. Oh well...

Comment: "frontotemperal dementia" - wow. Just wow.

Comment: "bat#$@@# insane" is probably too politically incorrect.

Comment: Much hate to DC for changing her origin to something boring.

Comment: @KutuluMike Even if it is thematically appropriate for Harley's usual foe.